# Load custom layout handle after catalog_category_view

Tags: magento-1.8, layout, event-observer, layout-update, update-handle

I am currently trying to load a custom layout handle after the catalog_category_view handle through the use of an observer that looks for the event `catalog_controller_category_init_after`.

The layout handle works when removing blocks, however ignores any layout update that adds a block to the layout.

Am I using the correct event to load the handle? 
Is there a better way of loading the custom layout handle?

Comment: can you post your layout update?

Comment: Hi Marius, Its not so much the update that's the problem but the actual loading of the handle. If I change the layout handle of my custom handle to <catalog_category_view> it works fine. As soon as I change it back to <new_catalog_category_view> it removes the specified blocks contained inside but doesn't add the blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `catalog_controller_category_init_after` is triggered *before the layout is loaded*. That means, if you add a layout handle in the observer for this event, it is the first one, before `catalog_category_view`, even before `default`. So any block you are referencing in your handle does not exist yet.

The `<remove>` tag works differently, it operates on the fully merged XML tree, that's why you can remove blocks. But instantiating blocks and executing actions happens in order of definition.

## Solution

Use a different event. A good choice is `controller_action_layout_render_before_catalog_category_view` which is triggered immediately before the layout is rendered, so you can be sure that it has been fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Now in latest magento version (2.4.X) the event is changed as $this->eventManager->dispatch('layout_render_before_' . $this->request->getFullActionName());

So for above case the new event will be layout_render_before_catalog_category_view

Thanks